# How to get the first three charecters of a string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called `AccountNumber` in a table `Accounts` with values as `32102`,`32103`,`35104`, `35106`,`32108`,`32110`,`32718`,`37651` where all the account numbers begining with `321XX` are `Liabilities` and the ones beginning with `351XX` are `Assets`.I need to select the accounts that falls under theses two categories and I am using the following query:

```
     SELECT * FROM 
     (SELECT  
       ACN.ACCOUNTNUMBER,
       ACN.CURRENTBALANCE,
        CASE 
          WHEN SUBSTR(ACN.ACCOUNTNUMBER,1,3) ='321'
            THEN 'LIABILITIES'
          WHEN SUBSTR(ACN.ACCOUNTNUMBER,1,3)='351'
            THEN 'ASSETS'
        END AS ACCOUNTCATEGORY
      FROM ACCOUNTS ACN
       WHERE ACN.FISCALYEAR='2015')ACCOUNTS
       WHERE ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTCATEGORY IS NOT NULL
```

My question here is regarding the use of the SUBSTR function.I am getting the same result while using :

```
                 SUBSTR(ACN.ACCOUNTNUMBER,1,3) ='321'
```

AND

```
                  SUBSTR(ACN.ACCOUNTNUMBER,0,3) ='321'
```

Can somebody please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: white character at the begining?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first position in string is considered to have position 1. If you provide a start position of 0, Oracle treats it as 1.

Quote from docs:
"If start_position is 0, then the SUBSTR function treats start_position as 1 (ie: the first position in the string)"

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) is very clear on this:

> - If position is 0, then it is treated as 1.